# How to select mssql schema by using php queries?

Tags: php, sql-server

I had a issue when tried to restore prod database into a dev database because it is divided by schema. Is it possible to select schema using PHP code?

Comment: Not certain what "select ... schema" means but you can set the default schema for the user specified in your connection string. The database engine uses that default when resolving object names that are not schema-qualified.

Comment: It meas that the database structure in prod didn´t use a schema division, but  dev structrue did.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PHP has a built in function to do this, but i have found a solution that worked very well for me.

```
function setSchema($query, $schema) {
    $query = str_ireplace('from ', "from {$schema}.", $query);
    $query = str_ireplace('update ', "update {$schema}.", $query);
    $query = str_ireplace('join ', "join {$schema}.", $query);
    $query = str_ireplace('into ', "into {$schema}.", $query);
    return $query;
}
```